# Laravel - why json response return sometimes an array sometimes an object

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

Here is my code :

```
    public function list()
    {
        $users = User::with('group')->get()->toArray();
        return response()->json([

            'clients' => array_filter($users, function ($r) {
                return $r['group']['name'] === 'client';
            }),

            'employes' => array(array_filter($users, function ($r) {
                return $r['group']['name'] !== 'client';
            })),

        ]);
    }
```

Here is the response :

```
{
  "clients": {
    "2": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Client 1",
      "email": "client@a.fr",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "group_id": 4,
      "group": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "client"
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Client 2",
      "email": "client2@a.fr",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "group_id": 4,
      "group": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "client"
      }
    },
    "4": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Client 3",
      "email": "client3@a.fr",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "group_id": 4,
      "group": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "client"
      }
    }
  },
  "employes": [
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alexis",
        "email": "alexis@a.fr",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "group_id": 1,
        "group": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "admin"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "guest",
        "email": "guest@a.fr",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "group_id": 2,
        "group": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "guest"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tried to change the conditions of the `array_filter`. Sometimes I have an array, sometimes I have an object. I don't understand how this is determined

Stackoverflow tells me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." So ... what details to add?

Thank you

Comment: It's an issue with the indices; JS will handle non-0-based arrays as objects. Your `clients` return has the first index of `2`, not `0`. I _think_ you can just wrap `array_filter` with `array_values` to reset the indices.

Comment: "JS will handle non-0-based arrays as objects."  Thank you for this information , its done

Comment: Exactly as he says, your array filter returns an array which start with the index 2, in JS you can't have that, so the json_encode turn it into an object

Comment: @TimLewis i suggest you put an answer with some documentation so he can close his question by selecting it as THE answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Internally `array_filter()` filters matching entries from the array, and returns them **with their indices intact**. This is very important, as it is the core reason you're getting an `object` and not an `array` in `JavaScript`.

In `PHP`, this is fine; arrays can start at 0, or another index, such as `2`, and function as an array without issue. This is due to the existence of `indexed` (0-based) and `associative` (numeric/non-numeric key based) arrays.

In `JavaScript`, arrays cannot be "associative", i.e. they must start at 0. `object` classes on the other hand function similarly to associative arrays, but the key difference is that they aren't explicitly arrays.

Now that you know the why, the next question is "how do I fix this?" The simple method is to wrap `array_filter()` with a function that simply returns the values of the new array. This inherently will "re-index" the array with 0-based values, which when converted to JSON will result in correct arrays being returned:

```
$users = User::with('group')->get()->toArray();

$clients = array_filter($users, function($r){
  return $r['group']['name'] === 'client';
});

$groups = array_filter($users, function ($r) {
  return $r['group']['name'] !== 'client';
});

return response()->json([
  'clients' => array_values($clients),
  'groups' => array_values($groups)
]);
```

As a sidenote, `Collection` classes have similar logic, and I prefer to use Laravel's `Collection` class whenever possible:

```
$users = User::with('group')->get();

$clients = $users->filter(function($r){
  $r->group->name === 'client';
});

$groups = $users->filter(function($r){
  $r->group->name !== 'client';
});

return response()->json([
  'clients' => $clients->values(),
  'groups' => $groups->values()
]);
```

But again, that's my preference; either approach should work, so use what you're used to.

References:

`PHP` Array Methods:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Laravel Collection Methods:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-values

Comment: As a follow up, what causes the intermittent behavior? Just ran into this as well, and its interesting to me that sometimes the array will serialize as a JSON array and sometimes as a numerically indexed object.

Comment: It comes down to how indexed and associative arrays exist in PHP, but not in Javascript. If you send a PHP array `[0, 1]` to JS as JSON, you'll get an array, since in both languages, it's represented as `[0,  1]` (or `[0 => 0, 1 => 1]` in PHP vs `{0: 0, 1: 1}` in JS (a 0-based indexed array). If you send a PHP array `[1 => 1, 2 => 2]` to JS as JSON, you'll get an Object `{1: 1, 2: 2}`, since arrays can _only_ be 0-based indexed in JS, but PHP allows arrays to have non-0 indices, like `['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b']`, etc. That would be `{a: 'a', b: 'b'}` as an object in JS.

Answer (score 2):

simply add ->values() it will reorder array keys

```
users = User::with('group')->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

> This works for me. I hope this will help anyone.

```
return response(['STATUS'=>'true','message'=>'Your Message','response'=> 
array_values('clients' => array_filter($users, function ($r) {
   return $r['group']['name'] === 'client';
})),
'employes' => array_values(array_filter($users, function ($r) {
   return $r['group']['name'] !== 'client';
}))
)]);
```

If in response array you will get a result like an index key and you want the response in object array [{ ... }] then use array_values() will resolve your problem.

"clients": {
"2": {
"id": 3,
"name": "Client 1",
"email": "client@a.fr",
"email_verified_at": null,
"created_at": null,
"updated_at": null,
"group_id": 4,
"group": {
"id": 4,
"name": "client"
}
},