# How to return array of arrays in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have a problem with this response

```
{
"success": {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "omar",
    "date": "2021-08-13",
    "start_time": "12:50:00",
    "end_time": "23:00:00",
    "end_date_time": "2021-08-13 23:00:00",
    "percentage": 10,
    "instruction": "asdadffa",
    "status": 1,
    "is_taken": 0,
    "is_closed": 0,
    "is_waiting": 0,
    "is_running": 0,
    "auto_mark": 0,
    "active_status": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-08-13T12:49:21.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-08-13T12:49:43.000000Z",
    "class_id": 1,
    "section_id": 1,
    "subject_id": 2,
    "created_by": 1,
    "updated_by": 1,
    "school_id": 1,
    "academic_id": 1
}}
```

I want to remove the internal brackets `{}` of success a replace it with `[]`

and here is my ideal response, something like that

```
{
"success": [
"id": 11,
"title": "omar",
"academic_id": 1
]}
```

thank you

Comment: try with toArray() collection method https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-toarray

Comment: I've tried that too, no luck!

Comment: Removing the brackets `{}`  would make it invalid JSON. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @brombeer sorry I just forgot to remove the ```,``` the response was big os I cut it off
I have updated my question

Comment: I just wanted to be an array, I want to replace these brackets with ```[]```

Comment: So you want to replace, not remove. That would make it invalid, as mentioned already. [json_​decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) has a second parameter you might want to use

Comment: please clarify what you are trying to do. yuor question is not clear. I am not able to understand what is your final goal

Comment: thanks everyone for replying, I have updated my answer, I hope this made some clarity

Comment: So, how should your final output Json look like with []?

Comment: I've just updated my answer @nice_dev

Comment: You are trying to make an array behave like an object without it actually being an object, so the exact structure is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

the way, you want the response will make it an invalid json. since an array in json object can't contain `key-value` pair data. An array in json can have multiple json objects in it. You can have the response like this:

```
{
    "success": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "title": "omar",
            "academic_id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

To understand your need, can I please know why do you need that type of response? by the way, the response you are getting is a valid json response.

Comment: the front end asked this format, and I couldn't do it! so I came here

Comment: Providing data in this format is not possible. So it would be better for you to contact with the front end. The first response in you question is a valid response and front end should do the work with that response.

Answer (score 0):

try like  this add toArray()

```
 $user= User::all()->toArray();
$post= Post::all()->toArray();
$comment= Comment:all()->toArray();

Response::json(['user'=>$user,'post'=>$post,'comment'=>$comment]);
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but it didn't work!

Comment: please explain more but maybe this link help you  => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685133/laravel-why-json-response-return-sometimes-an-array-sometimes-an-object

Comment: or this one ```return Response::json($posts->toArray());```

Answer (score 0):

$user= User::all()->toArray();

return response()->json(['user'=>$user]);

Comment: thanks for answering, but it didn't work!

Comment: try this    return response()->json([
    'user' => $user->values()->toArray()
]);