# Laravel collection chunk() method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I'm building an application on `Laravel` where I'm trying to store 100 datasets into `DynamoDB`, after reading the documentation `DynamoDB` can only accept 25 records at a time so I'm trying to store this in chunks of 25.

For this I tried to use Laravel's collection method, but somehow the format is getting changed and I'm getting DynamoDB error `SerializationException`, here's my code:

```
$posts = collect($request->posts)->map(function ($items){
  //... transforming the array and returning it
})->chunk(25)

foreach($posts->all() as $chunk) {         
    Post::batchPutItem(collect($chunk)->toArray());
}


return response()->json(['data' => $posts], 200);
```

First 25 records are saved appropriately, I start getting errors from second iteration. When I inspected the data/returned the chunk I found that data gets transformed

[image: returned results]

As you can see the first chunk is in array, but next chunk becomes object.

I even tried `->chunk(25, true)` but no luck.

Any solution or work around to this?

Comment: Why are you collecting the chunk again?

Comment: @aynber I tried without collecting the chunk, but the results happened to be the same. I thought it could be transformed into an array.

Comment: That's how JS handles non-zero-index/non-sequential arrays; it converts them to objects with each index (25, 26, ...) being an object key, since JS doesn't support associative arrays like PHP does. I'm not quite sure the solution here... Typically you'd use `array_values`, or Laravel's Collection `->values()` method, but I'm not sure how you'd handle this with chunking logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685133/laravel-why-json-response-return-sometimes-an-array-sometimes-an-object/59687076#59687076 - For clarification. If you do `return response()->json([1 => 0, 2 => 1])` (associative array), you'll get an object, where as `return response()->json([0, 1])` (indexed array), you'll get an array.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks Tim `array_values(collect($chunk)->toArray())` worked.

Comment: Sweet! Sidenote, `collect($chunk)->toArray()` is redundant; you're collecting an array to simply convert it to an array again; this could simply be `array_values($chunk)`, or similar. Cheers though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked in the comments show the underlying reason. JS handles associative arrays in PHP by converting them to objects, with each index used as an object key. To get around this, you'd need to further map the `$posts`:

```php
return response()->json(['data' => $posts->map(function ($chunk) {
  return $chunk->values();
  /* or `return array_values($chunk)` if `$chunk` is an Array instead of a Collection */
}], 200);
```

With a simple dataset of:

```php
$posts = collect([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])->chunk(4);

echo json_encode($posts);
echo json_encode($posts->map(function ($chunk) { 
  return $chunk->values();
});
```

The first will output what you're seeing:

```php
[[0,1,2,3],{"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7}]
```

While the second will output it as you're expecting:

```php
[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]
```

Links for reference:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-values

https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php